# How should we react to exact copied answers?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, ethics

Yesterday I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32331811/1841194) that is *exactly* copied and pasted from its upper answer. This is definitely [considered as plagiarism](http://www.plagiarism.org/plagiarism-101/what-is-plagiarism/). I commented "Please delete your answer.". But she didn't, as another user also already had commented that this is not ethical.

In short, my question is: How should we react to such behaviors? (Generally plagiarisms)

Comment: Downvote, flag and hunt: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/246262)

Comment: The entire question is rife with terrible answers.  For example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090832/android-studio-cant-start-after-installation/33383606#33383606) has **exactly** the same problem as the one you identified.  And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090832/android-studio-cant-start-after-installation/32113492#32113492) is a comment with a link to a possible solution.

Comment: Plagiarism is the lesser evil here, this is a voting ring at work.  Only way to get 6 upvotes on an answer like that.  A quicky way to get, say, a fellow class mate enough rep to participate.  We'll get it deleted easy enough but it is better if the ring is larsoned.  Brad won't necessarily see it if you don't flag the post.

Comment: Wow. Looks like this question is a NAA magnet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33708016/1842065

Comment: @HansPassant this question seems to keep picking up bad non-answer answers.  In fact one was added while this post was being discussed.  Would you mind protecting it please

Comment: @psub - I did, but changed my mind. I don't want to piss off that subcontinent.  They have their votes and are clearly not afraid to use them.  If there is anybody left in [android] that still cares enough then they can do it.

Comment: @HansPassant fair enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On that particular answer, I think it may be unclear whether they're plagiarising or whether they're quoting the other answer and stating it worked for them (the user doesn't really have enough of a history to sway me one way or the other so, being the nice guy I am, I'd probably give them the benefit of the doubt, i.e., assume it's the latter case).

However, it makes little difference to the eventual outcome. If the former (plagiarism), I'd simply downvote as not useful (justified by the fact it *adds* nothing to the answer already given) and make sure you *upvote* the other useful answers. That way, it floats toward the bottom as intended.

If the latter ("the above answer worked for me"), simply flag as not-an-answer, since it really isn't an answer.

For *general* plagiarism, I tend to adopt the first option above. If enough of the swarm do this, the answer disappears.

Comment: I actually read it as "(the procedure mentioned) worked for me!" which constitues Not An Answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. I hope the latter applies. So I just flagged it as "Not an Answer".

Comment: @HiI'mfrogatto NAA may not work as it is not very obvious.  It looks like an attempt to answer, so may not be seen for what it is.  If the NAA fails, I suggest a custom moderator flag explaining the problem

Comment: What about the voting ring, then (see the comments to the question)?

Comment: @Peter, a six-bod voting ring won't be able to overcome (for long) good people doing the right thing. Downvotes and/or close/delete-votes would remove whatever rep was gained. In any case, I understand SO can *already* detect rings if they're blatant enough.